# Не получается задать статичную папку для Express на Javascript

Tags: javascript, express, файловая-система

Есть пример из учебника (Пьюривал С. Основы разработки веб-приложений, 2015, стр 197). Там создается виртуальная машина и на ней запускается сервер на JavaScript, используется модуль http и Express.

```
var express = require("express"),
http = require("http"),
app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client")); 
//в папке есть файл index.html
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
app.get("/hello", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Hello, World!");
});
app.get("/goodbye", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Goodbye, World!");
});
```

При использовании ссылки http://localhost:3000/index.html пишет : Cannot GET /index.html. При этом предыдущие примеры(где нет запроса к файлам) работают, а этот - нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: index.html у Вас точно лежит в подпапке client?
Вот прямо сейчас проверил Ваш код, все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была в неправильном размещении каталога client. Хотя делал все по учебнику, но по мануалам Express надо в тот же каталог, где находится исполняемый файл server.js. __dirname как раз туда и ведет. Прочитал внимательнее учебник:все из-за плохого перевода(сначала указывается создание папки в одном месте, а потом в контексте указывается, что папка должна быть в другом). Хотелось бы узнать, если не укажу глоб переменную, то где должен будет находится client?